# Message Enricher and variables

Tags: mule

I"m having a hard time realizing something from the documentation.

What i'd like to do is to to enrich the current payload with a simple int.

Could i do that staticly from the enricher syntax or would i have to create an outbound request-reaponse endpoint just for that silly thing?

For example, i am looking for the somethinga lone the lines of:

```
 <enricher target="#[variable:age]" source="SomeStringIwant"/>
```

That obviously would not work, is there some way to get it to work easily?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the comment. My payload type will be a java bean. I want to use the message enricher inorder to "set" a field of that java bean.

Comment: Could i do that or would it have to be a transformer? and if so, how would i go about passing an int variable to the transformer from the flow? , Thanks!

Comment: Enricher cannot be used to modify the payload "NOTE: Mule currently supports enrichment of flow variables and message headers only."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [script transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Scripting+Module+Reference#ScriptingModuleReference-Script) for this:

```
<script:transformer>
    <script:script engine="groovy">
        <script:text>
            payload.age = message.getInboundProperty('ageProperty')
            return payload
        </script:text>
    </script:script>
</script:transformer>
```

This script assumes the 'ageProperty' is in the inbound scope. If not, use the method for the right scope.

This script also relies on two of the [implicit variables bound in the context](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Scripting+Module+Reference#ScriptingModuleReference-ScriptContextBindings) of a script transformer:

- payload: an Object carried by the current message, as you can get it with [MuleMessage.getPayload](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#getPayload%28%29).
- message: the in-flight [MuleMessage](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html) as [carried by the current MuleEvent](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleEvent.html#getMessage%28%29).

Comment: Hmm. Could you give a quick explanation as to what is the message type you're using? The payload is what running through the flow, whats the message?

Comment: Sure, added more info re:implicitly bound script variables.